# Wrong package.appxmanifest picked by msbuild when packaging in command line

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, packaging

I have a C# solution with VS 2017, containing an app project, a desktop extension project, and a packaging project. As I mentioned in the [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892208/uwp-with-desktop-bridge-package-build-automation-with-msbuild/53181888#53181888), I finally get msbuild to create a single bundle with both x86 and x64 for me. However, after I tried to install from that bundle, I found that msbuild actually picked up the wrong package.appxmanifest because they have different version numbers.

So... I have two package.appxmanifest, one in packaging project, and one in my main app project. When I build from the wizard in VS 2017, the one in packaging project will be used, which is correct. When I use msbuild to build with just one platform, it will pick the right one as well, like this:

```
msbuild .\MyApp.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86
```

Only when I use msbuild to build two platforms together, it will use the one in my main app project:

```
msbuild .\MyApp.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64" /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload
```

I also tried to build the packaging project instead of the solution, but because our desktop extension project is only x86, I will get errors about configurations when building x64.

Questions:

1. Does anyone know why this is happening?
2. I am also very confused about how to build multi-platform using AppxBundlePlatforms in the command line. Since I cannot specify the platform, which platform is used to build?
3. Should I add `<AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>` or `<AppxBundle>Never</AppxBundle>` to the packaging project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Does anyone know why this is happening?

That because you have two `Package.appxmanifest` files with same ID in the solution. When you create the App Bundle with `.sln`, MSBuild/Visual Studio could not to know clearly which `Package.appxmanifest` should be use.

> 2. I am also very confused about how to build multi-platform using AppxBundlePlatforms in the command line. Since I cannot specify the
>      platform, which platform is used to build?

Not sure the reason why you can not specify the platform. To resolve this issue, you can try yo build the project file `.csproj` instead of the solution file. For example, when you build the app project, you can use the command line:

```
msbuild .\MyApp.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64"
```

And then build the packaging project:

```
msbuild .\YouPackaging.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86"
```

> 3. Should I add Always or
>      Never to the packaging project?

If you build the project, no need to add those two properties to the project file, those two properties are used to the solution level and you have a project that you do not want to add to the bundle:

> because at the solution level, it’s not clear which app should appear
>   in the bundle. To resolve this issue, open each project file and add
>   the following properties at the end of the first 
>   element

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. For question 2, I thought that AppxBundlePlatforms is used for creating a bundle only, does that also imply msbuild will also pick the right platform to build the code? How does it work with the argument "Platform"?

Comment: Also, with your example for question 2, ,does it just build x86 for packaging? my packaging project is a wapproj, and when I tried I got errors about platform is set to ' ', like this: "Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform=''."

Comment: For 1, should I have two appxmanifest then? How do I let msbuild know I want to use the one in packaging project?

Sorry for asking a lot of questions. I think our project has a complicated setup...

Comment: @laishiekai, Sorry for the late reply due to weekend reasons. For the question 1 in the comments, yes, MSBuild also pick the right platform to build base on the `AppxBundlePlatforms`. For the question 2, it seems you are not give the specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project, you should make sure the parameters in the command line are match your projects.

Comment: @laishiekai, If you want to build the two  App Bundle package, you should have two appxmanifest. If not, you just move the one you do not want. If you build the solution file, it seems that you can not specify the appxmanifest file in the command line, I have not seen this before, sorry :(. That the reason why I suggest that specify the project file instead of the solution file.

Comment: Update: After discussing with MS support, we found that msbuild has a bug that it cannot handle multi-platform bundle using /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64" properly. Currently the workaround way would be just build single platform and upload two bundle to the MS store. MS is looking into this issue now.